# Coverity is pointing to a potential memory leak

Tags: c++, coverity

Coverity is pointing out to a potential memory leak in the following code.

```
m_threads.create_thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &m_ioService));
```

The coverity error is as follows:

```
CID 223450 (#1 of 1): Resource leak (RESOURCE_LEAK)
8. leaked_storage: Ignoring storage allocated by this->m_threads.create_thread(boost::bind(&run, &this->m_ioService)) leaks it
```

The code for create_thread is as follows:

```
template<typename F>
thread* create_thread(F threadfunc)
{
    boost::lock_guard<shared_mutex> guard(m);
    std::auto_ptr<thread> new_thread(new thread(threadfunc));
    threads.push_back(new_thread.get());
    return new_thread.release();
}
```

The type of new_thread is:

```
std::auto_ptr<thread> new_thread(new thread(threadfunc));
```

The type of threads is:

```
std::list<thread*> threads;
```

The destructor of the class thread_group (which has the method create_thread and member threads) deletes all threads:

```
  for(std::list<thread*>::iterator it=threads.begin(),end=threads.end();
     it!=end;
     ++it)
 {
     delete *it;
 }
```

Based on this do you think there is a memory leak or this one is a false postive.

Comment: Using `std::auto_ptr` have been advised against ever since it was introduced. It was deprecated in the C++11 standard and removed in the C++17 standard. You really should migrate away from it ASAP.

Comment: Also, with the way you use `std::auto_ptr` in the shown code, it's really useless anyway. You could just as well do `threads.push_back(new thread(threadfunc));` instead of bothering with `std::auto_ptr`.

Comment: If only I could.... This is a company code and the boost and pthread libraries used here are really outdated. It's kind of, from very difficult to impossible for me to update these and other outdated libraries. The question though is, even by using std::auto_ptr, is there a leak here? I just can't see it...

Comment: If the destructor runs the code you show, and you don't "reset" or "clear" the list or otherwise modify the pointers in any way, then that should be enough and it looks like a false positive. But with only the limited code you show it's kind of hard to tell for sure.

Comment: This is a [boost code](https://github.com/boostorg/thread/blob/boost-1.55.0/include/boost/thread/detail/thread_group.hpp) and as I said I have no power to update it. Max I can do is to mark the coverity issue as a "false postive ". So please comment on wheather it's safe to do so.

Comment: So much of the code you show is from inside the Boost library? Then yes it should be safe to mark it as a false positive. And in the future, even if it's hard, *please* try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us. And *clearly* tell us which parts of the code you show is your own, and which is from a third-party library.